# Searching on a value and displaying another on Dojo FilteringSelect

Tags: zend-framework, dojo, dijit.form

I'm using the dojo FilteringSelect element together on a Zend form, but I cannot make it work as I want. I have a store with three fields `id`, `label`, `name`. Label will be used for the dropdown and should **also** be used for the search, while `name` should be used for te display inside the box. The problem is that I can't find a way to make this behavior work.

Setting the `labelAttr` value to `label` works showing it on the dropdown, but the `searchAttr` attribute governs both the search AND the display on the input box once a value is selected. I need to search the `label` field since it is a collection of many fields, but display the value on `name`, is it possible?

EDIT: @RichardAyotte The Dijit FilteringSelect widget uses a dojo.data.store, which is basically a javascript object, where each item is also an object with many parameters. You can set two special parameters on the store: **labelAttr** and **searchAttr** which will define a couple of behaviors. The FilteringSelect is tied to an INPUT box where you can search. If you click the box it will open the list of options, like a  would. Here it shows whatever you defined as labelAttr. Now, if you type on the box, it will *search* on the store, using what is defined on the **searchAttr** field. It ALSO used the value of label to be display inside the input once you select something from the list (you can check it here http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dijit/form/FilteringSelect.html#displaying-rich-text-menu-labels-with-labelattr-and-labeltype)

What I wanted to do is "decouple" the **searchAttr** field into 2 different fields one for search and another to be used for display inside the input. AFAICT it is not possible though, and I will have to extend the FilteringSelect object

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to have the ability to search one column while seeing the results of another. How can this work? As the user is typing, from which column are the partial results shown?

Comment: @RichardAyotte from the visible column. I see nothing particularly strange in that requirement - it's just like Google works.

Comment: @RichardAyotte I EDIT the question with a longer explanation

Answer (score 1):

You can do this kind of thing with AOP. See [dojo/aspect](http://livedocs.dojotoolkit.org/dojo/aspect).

**caveat**: adding advice to private function _announceOption.

```
var countryField = new FilteringSelect({
    label: 'Country'
    , name: 'country_id'
    , searchAttr: 'name'
    , labelAttr: 'label'
    , store: new CountryStore()
});

aspect.around(countryField, '_announceOption', function(origFunction) {
    return function(node) {
        this.searchAttr = 'label'
        var r = origFunction.call(this, node);
        this.searchAttr = 'name'
        return r;
    }
})
```

Comment: Cool, I will try it as soon as I get to that code again, and I will post here if it worked.

Comment: So it did not work. Checking the result of the origFunction call it looks like the search was performed correctly but the dropdown with the filtered options did not appear once it finished. I'm not sure if it might be the reason, but the store uses an ajax call to search\filter the results. I will try to change that behavior to see if it works.

Comment: I tried this code with a JsonRest store without problems. Can you post the code that doesn't work. Also, this was done with Dojo 1.9.1.